# :hover works in firebug but not in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have created a div and on hover I want the background color to turn red. When I view it in Firefox and mouseover the div nothing happens. I can inspect it in Firebug and force the hover class - which works! But why is it not working as it should in the browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <button>
    <div class="outer-circle">
     <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
    </div>
 </button>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS is as follows:

```
.outer-circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.outer-circle:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Based on that info I would say most likely the block level paragraph element is stealing the mouse over and of course p:hover doesn't have any styles. Bit strange though I don't recall it working that way.

Comment: Remove the button tag it will work.

Comment: Yeah, i'd say that button is a suplement for input type submit - inputs are not made to contain nested elements (only text) - this is my hunch

Answer (score 1):

Give the hover style like this below instead of .outer-cirlce:hover

```
button:hover .outer-circle {
    background-color: red;
}
```

It will work. Try it

Comment: Thanks everyone but this answer worked best for me! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just Use html like this text also center in the circle

```
<button class="outer-circle">
    <div>
     <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
    </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as per your requirement also you can see in snippet. So implemet this code I hope it will work for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  
  <style>
  .outer-circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: table;
}
.outer-circle p{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0;
}

.outer-circle:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
button:hover .outer-circle {
    background-color: red;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button>
    <div class="outer-circle">
     <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
    </div>
 </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

https://plnkr.co/edit/JlGWuI3UB2ChMNS2YyK3?p=preview

```
<div class="outer-circle" onclick="clickFunc()">
 <p>HELLO WORLD!</p>
</div>
```

You placed the circle div inside the button tag so that hover class is not working.

I have changed the structure added click function on 'outer-circle' class. Hope this helps.